# Change/Remove buttons or button texts on remote notification

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [add buttons to push notification alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190089/add-buttons-to-push-notification-alert)

Is it possible specify the payload to change/remove buttons or button texts ("close" & "view" buttons) in the alert box that shows from remote notifications? I can't find any information about this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @madhu suggested try reading [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/PayloadKeyReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH17-SW1). It might help you.