# Push notifications show custom alert

Tags: ios, push-notification

In my app, I am adding push notification support.
In that can I show alert with "join" and "cancel" buttons instead of "view" and "cancel"?

Comment: It appears you can. Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190089/add-buttons-to-push-notification-alert)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, its possible to change the "View" to "Join" button.

It has action-loc-key parameter to be set in push notification.
Look at the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/PayloadKeyReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH17-SW1)