# iOS APNS alert with buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

The Facebook Messenger has a great feature in its APNS alerts: they put 2 buttons:
[image]

I can't find is it possible to mere mortals to customize alerts like this or this feature is available for Facebook only?
Official [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html) provide only customizing text, sound, badge and an additional falg.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190089/add-buttons-to-push-notification-alert ?

Comment: https://nrj.io/simple-interactive-notifications-in-ios-8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since iOS8 this feature is provided in APNS have a look at this

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#713